# Can't build apk because of Cordova plugin that seems to overwrite Theme.AppCompat

Tags: java, android, cordova, apk, cordova-plugins

I'm having an issue with a plugin called cordova-plugin-kiosk. I did not have this issue before but I'm unable to build the apk successfully or the app crashes in the emulator. It seems it has something to do with the following setting in the AndroidManifest.xml `android:theme="@android:style/Theme.DeviceDefault.NoActionBar"`. I'm not sure what to replace that with and still make the plugin work. Also here is the error I get in the log:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.tablezig.v6/org.cordova.plugin.labs.kiosk.KioskActivity}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with this activity.
```

Answer (score 1):

I fixed the issue by adding the following to AndroidManifest.xml in the `<activity>`
`android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.DayNight.NoActionBar"`